# Pick up a phone line using a PC

Tags: windows, modem

Hey, everyone. I am needing to record the end of a phone call to obtain a specific (that is, obscure) recording so that I can play it back from my pc as an answering machine.

I can already play back sound files, and answer calls no problem (and also record the end of the phone call, but I have to dial with my pc which is inconvenient to me). The issue is that I cannot find any way to pick up a phone line like you can with a physical phone!

The recording only happens about 1 out of 4 times, and I want to be able to pick up the phone line (as if it were another extension) either programatically or using whatever software that's out there.

I have searched for a couple hours now and have found many dialing softwares, none of which that can simply pick up the line ("hook") and play the output & send input (from mic) as if it's a phone.

I really don't care whether I implement it myself or not; I am proficient in several programming languages. I just don't want to waste time making it myself if there's a library or existing software to do it for me.

Oh, an I am using windows. (Though, a solution for linux might not be bad. I'd have to figure out how to loop back audio on linux, though haha)

Thanks! And by the way, I am NOT wanting VoIP - I want to use my computer's modem!

UPDATE: Evidently, sending "ATH1" to my modem port (COM4) should unhook the line. However, my driver is not working properly so i am installing the proper driver. update coming soon...

UPDATE 2: Finally got *A* modem working, it turns out my built-in one does not work (possibly fried?) so I am now using a modem that plugs into the PC card slot. Supposedly, it's using COM6 as it's ort and dialing out works fine using the windows phone dialer, but none of the "AT*" commands seem to do anything. If I pick up a (real) extension elsewhere in the house and try again, it makes a very distant click sound. Every time I echo an AT* command to the modem it seems to write it then returns to the dos prompt immediately. I'm not sure what's happening; perhaps I'm echoing the at* commands wrong, or am forgetting a prerequisite at* command before hooking/dialing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory you have to tell the modem to answer automatically when the phone rings.

Sending

```
AT S0=1
```

will cause the modem to answer on the first ring.

If you want to do it manually after some program logic or something, try issuing

```
AT A
```

when the phone is ringing.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear; I already know how to pick up the line when waiting for a call. I cannot, however, pick up the line whilst someone else is talking - which is what I need.

Comment: Ah, I see.

ATH1 should work. Let us know once you have the driver fixed.

Comment: I don't know if I'm not typing the commands correctly or what, but all ATH1 does is makes a distant click sound - if you listen on a another line. The computer itself makes no sound whatsoever... :\ All I want to do is pick up the line and hear what's being said, how freaking hard should that be????

Comment: Troubleshooting now -  Is the Speaker perhaps off?   
Try 
ATM2    to turn Speaker on
ATL3    to turn volume up

Or try ATA  instead of ATH1  and see what happens?

Comment: Alrighty! It works. The drawback is that there is no sound, and nothing can be sent over the modem via microphone. Turns out that if I use "ATH1" then "ATDT *********" (** being a phone #) and listen on another line, it does sound. Thus, the modem works. The modem is this little card that is about the size of 4-5 credit cards stacked, and is a little longer than a credit card. I'm guessing that there's just no option for sound on it? (I think it's called a "PC Card", but I'm not sure) - Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh, forgot to add that while listening on another line, issuing "ATA" causes a sound similar to that of a fax machine. (On another line; the computer still makes no sound.)

Comment: Hey, Ok, that makes a lot of sense.

That triggers my memory - back when modems were popular there was a special type of modem called a Voice Modem, which did the normal modem things but also handled voice.  Mine even had  microphone and headphone jacks.   

Do you have the option of trying another modem?

Comment: Meh, no jacks on it whatsoever. No other modems. It's no big deal, we ended up cutting our home phone service anyway. Thanks a ton for the help! (P.S. - it was a zoom pcmcia card, read the manual and the command was: AT+FCLASS=8 to enable voice, supposedly - didn't get a chance to try it.)